# need to source bash_profile in each new iterm window

Tags: macbook-pro, alias, osx-el-capitan, .bash-profile, iterm

I am on macbook pro, el capitan. I have aliases set in `.bash_profile`, which work in the first instance of `iTerm`, however they are not recognized if I open a new `iTerm` instance, I have to do `source ~/.bash_profile` each time.

Can they somehow be remembered for all instances?

Answer (score 2):

go to settings and under Profile > General > Command select "Command" radio button and use `/bin/bash --login` as the command. This will load your `.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually for newest macOS you go to GUI of the terminal and in the:

> *Terminal Preferences* → *Profiles* → *Shell*

In the "Startup" option activate the "Run Command" and type `source ~/.profile`.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on if it is a login shell or an interactive one, bash will source either the `~/.bash_profile` or the `~/.bashrc`. iTerm is most likely looking for `~/.bashrc`.

You can simply put a line at the beginning of each file:
At the top of `~/.bash_profile`

```
export BASH_CONF="bash_profile"
```

At the top of `~/.bashrc`

```
export BASH_CONF="bashrc"
```

And then simply type `$ echo $BASH_CONF` in a new iTerm instance.